# GUI - приложение не видит переменную + некорректная работа GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

Вопрос по коду из книги Майкла Доусона "Программируем на Python".
Вот сам код:

```
# Сумасшедший сказочник
# Создаёт рассказ на основе пользовательского ввода

from tkinter import *


class Application(Frame):
    """ GUI - приложение, создающее рассказ на основе пользовательского ввода """

    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        """ Создаёт элементы управления для пользователя """
        # Метка с текстом-инструкцией
        Label(self,
              text="Введите данные для создания нового рассказа"
              ).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        # Метка и поле ввода для имени человека
        Label(self,
              text="Имя человека: "
              ).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.person_ent = Entry(self)
        self.person_ent.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
        # Метка и поле ввода для существительного
        Label(self,
              text="Существительное во мн.ч.: "
              ).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.noun_ent = Entry(self)
        self.noun_ent.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
        # Метка и поле ввода для глагола
        Label(self,
              text="Глагол в инфинитиве: "
              ).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.verb_ent = Entry(self)
        self.verb_ent.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)
        # Метка при группе флажков с прилагательными
        Label(self,
              text="Прилагательное (-ые):"
              ).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)
        # Флажок со словом "нетерпеливый"
        self.is_itchy = BooleanVar()
        Checkbutton(self,
                    text="нетерпеливый",
                    variable=self.is_itchy
                    ).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)
        # Флажок со словом "радостный"
        self.is_joyous = BooleanVar
        Checkbutton(self,
                    text="радостный",
                    variable=self.is_joyous
                    ).grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=W)
        # Флажок со словом "пронизывающий"
        self.is_electric = BooleanVar
        Checkbutton(self,
                    text="пронизывающий",
                    variable=self.is_electric
                    ).grid(row=4, column=3, sticky=W)
        # Метка при переключателе с названиями частей тела
        Label(self,
              text="Часть тела:",
              ).grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W)
        # Переменная, содержащая название одной из частей тела
        self.body_part = StringVar()
        self.body_part.set(None)
        # Переключатель с названиями частей тела
        body_parts = ["пупок", "большой плец ноги", "продолговатый мозг"]
        column = 1
        for part in body_parts:
            Radiobutton(self,
                        variable=self.body_part,
                        value=part
                        ).grid(row=5, column=column, sticky=W)
            column += 1
        # Кнопка отсылки данных
        Button(self,
               text="Получить рассказ",
               command=self.tell_story()
               ).grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.story_txt = Text(self, width=75, height=10, wrap=WORD)
        self.story_txt.grid(row=7, column=0, columnspan=4)

    def tell_story(self):
        """ Заполняет текстовую область очередной историей """
        # Получение значений от пользователя
        person = self.person_ent.get()
        noun = self.noun_ent.get()
        verb = self.verb_ent.get()
        adjectives = ""
        if self.is_itchy.get():
            adjectives += "нетерпеливое, "
        if self.is_joyous.get():
            adjectives += "радостное, "
        if self.is_electric.get():
            adjectives += "пронизывающее, "
        body_part = self.body_part.get()
        # Создание рассказа
        story = "Знаменитый путешественник " + person + " уже совсем отчаялся довершить дело всей своей жизни - " \
                + "поиск затерянного города, в котором, по легенде, обитали " + noun + ". Но однажды " + noun + " и " \
                + person + " столкнулись лицом к лицу. Мощное, " + adjectives + "ни с чем не сравнимое чувство охватило " \
                + "душу путешественника. После стольких лет поисков цель была наконец достигнута. " + person + " ощутил, " \
                + "как на его " + body_part + " скатилась слезинка. И тут внезапно " + noun + " перешли в атаку, и " \
                + person + " был ими мгновенно сожран. Мораль? Если задумали " + verb + ", надо делать это с осторожностью."
        # Вывод рассказа на экран
        self.story_txt.delete(0.0, END)
        self.story_txt.insert(0.0, story)


# Основная часть
root = Tk()
root.title("Сумасшедший сказочник")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Запустив его, получил следующую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Работа/Python/crazy_wizard/main.py", line 114, in <module>
    app = Application(root)
  File "D:/Работа/Python/crazy_wizard/main.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.create_widgets()
  File "D:/Работа/Python/crazy_wizard/main.py", line 80, in create_widgets
    command=self.tell_story()
  File "D:/Работа/Python/crazy_wizard/main.py", line 94, in tell_story
    if self.is_joyous.get():
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Попробовав убрать функцию get() в строках 94 и 96 (причём строка 92 выполняется без этой ошибки(!)), получил следующую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Работа/Python/crazy_wizard/main.py", line 114, in <module>
    app = Application(root)
  File "D:/Работа/Python/crazy_wizard/main.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.create_widgets()
  File "D:/Работа/Python/crazy_wizard/main.py", line 80, in create_widgets
    command=self.tell_story()
  File "D:/Работа/Python/crazy_wizard/main.py", line 107, in tell_story
    self.story_txt.delete(0.0, END)
AttributeError: 'Application' object has no attribute 'story_txt'
```

Перенеся по настоянию Pycharm-а инициализацию переменной story_txt в функцию **init** получил работающее (вернее, запускающееся) приложение, в котором:

1. Не меняется поле вывода (т.е. не работает кнопка "Получить рассказ"
2. Не отображаются названия переключателей (части тела)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.is_joyous = BooleanVar
```

- здесь не происходит создание переменной, а полю `is_joyous` присваивается класс `BooleanVar`. Из-за этого `self.is_joyous.get()` - это по сути попытка вызова метода от класса, а не от объекта: `BooleanVar.get()`. Любой обычный метод (не `classmethod` и не `staticmethod`) требует параметр `self`, а при вызове метода от класса этот параметр не передается, отсюда ошибка. Нужно добавить круглые скобки при создании переменной: `self.is_joyous = BooleanVar()`.

```
Button(self,
       text="Получить рассказ",
       command=self.tell_story()
       ).grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=W)
```

- здесь у вас не привязывается метод `tell_story` к нажатию на кнопку, а сразу вызывается этот метод, при чем до создания поля `story_txt`, отсюда `AttributeError`. Здесь нужно убрать круглые скобки после имени метода: `command=self.tell_story`.

В общем - следите за скобками, чтобы они были там где нужно, и их не было там где они не нужны.